# Why delegate value is not coming to textfield in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I am using delegate to get phone number country code.

here i have created delegate:

```
public protocol CountryListDelegate: class {
func selectedCountry(country: Country)
}

public class CountryList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {



   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CountryCell
    let country = cell.country!

    self.searchController?.isActive = false
    self.delegate?.selectedCountry(country: country)

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

here i am not getting the value in countryCodeTextfield:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CountryListDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var countryCodeTextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var counrtryCodeBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var mobileNumTextfield: UITextField!

var countryList = CountryList()

     @IBAction func submitBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("in submit")

if sender.tag == 1 {
 if (mobileNumTextfield.text?.count)!<1 {
     Constants.showAlertView(alertViewTitle: "", Message: "Please Enter Mobile Number", on: self)
     return
 }
 self.loginService()
 } else {
 let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: countryList)
 self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

 }
   func selectedCountry(country: Country) {
    print("in country")
    self.countryCodeTextfield.text="+\(country.phoneExtension)"
       print("\(country.flag!) \(country.name!), \(country.countryCode), \(country.phoneExtension)")
   }
```

above tableview is presenting but `selectedCountry` is not calling the print stament also not coming.

please help me in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegate

```
countryList.delegate = self
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: countryList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign CountryList delegate to self,  self is the ViewController which has been delegated!

```
//MARK: Create a delegate property in Country List.
 weak var delegate: CountryListDelegate?
```

After creating an instance of CountryList and assign its delegate to self

```
var countryList = CountryList()
countryList.delegate = self
```